# Mounting nfs4 partition over ssh tunel

Tags: debian, ubuntu, ssh, nfs, ssh-tunneling

I am following this manual on how to mount an nfs port over an ssh tunnel:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shepler/entry/tunneling_nfs_traffic_via_ssh

I need this because I want to mount an nfs partition from a machine that is behind a router with no static IP.

However, when I try and issue the mount command I get:

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers='4,tcp' -o port=3049  127.0.0.1:/mnt/shared /mnt/aaa -v
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Mar 16 18:49:14 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=4,tcp,port=3049,addr=127.0.0.1,clientaddr=127.0.0.1'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

What is causing this?
The NFS client mounts fine on the machine I am ssing to, and it not mounted when I issue the port forwarding.
Getting the same error on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: What does `exportfs` on your server day? Are there ACLs on the export? You might find `strace` gives you more answers as to exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: Will try, note I managed to get sshfs working so its less urgent

Comment: GuySoft, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @dds started using sshfs instead. With recent ubuntu it even pops up a dialog to put the password if you have one.
Use ``sshfs -o allow_other -o reconnect -o ServerAliveInterval=15 user@hostname.net:/remote/path /local/path``

Comment: Will note that sshfs keeps asking for password from time to time with ksshaskpass. It seems like every upgrade of kubuntu has a different behavior

Answer (score 1):

It's a number of years on, but I have just encountered this problem of not being able to mount an NFS share through an SSH tunnel.

In my case, it appears to be that the NFS server in debian/ubuntu by default allows connections only *from* specific low-numbered ports. The connection from the SSH tunnel appears to come from a random high-numbered port. Adding 'insecure' to the options in /etc/export changes this default behaviour to allow connections from any port.